# Is energy manipulation the same as telekinesis

Tags: magic

So, for my hard magic system, the "users" draw off energy from the parallel realm to manipulate energy on the physical plane. Going by that description, would it be a leap to give my characters telekinesis (or explained in my book as energy used to move things) If it helps, I also plan on giving them energy bolts that later evolve into lighting

Comment: Uh... it's your magic system. You can make it do whatever you want. Sanderson's first law of magic: An author’s ability to solve conflict with magic is DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to how well the reader understands said magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is telekinesis if it isn't accelerating an object relative to a frame of reference?  Or, in other words, gravity.

If you're willing to allow "psychic powers" and give people lighting bolts, I think the ability to condense the energy from a parallel realm into a point which allows one to manipulate an object at a distance by changing the gravitational gradients around that object.

Inexperienced gravitymancers might make the object gyrate wildly or hurl it in a direction due to inexperience, while experienced gravitficers might be able to precisely position objects, create effective antigravity amongst themselves, ignite fusion with their mind, etc.

Inexperienced gravity wizards may have a non-zero chance to "collapse" the object they are attempting to levitate by placing the gravity well too close with too much mass, destroying the object in the meantime.